# Linking HTML to JSP page

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm have problems linking my HTML and JSP. Just trying to make a simple html page to take a "email" and "password" then have the jsp display on the next page. But when i click submit the parameters dont get passed i just get "null", any ideas where im going wrong?

HTML Page

```
<html>

<head>
        <title>Enter your email and password</title>
</head>

<body>

        <form action="form.jsp" method="get">
        <table cellspacing="5" border="0">
                <tr>
                     <td align="right">Email:</td>
                     <td><input type="text" email=email></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td align="right">Password:</td>
                     <td><input type="text" password=password></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td></td>
                     <td><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JSP Page

```
<html>
<body>

        <%
        // get info from request
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        %>

        <p>Here is the info you provided:</p>

        <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Email:</td>
                <td><%= email %></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password:</td>
                <td><%= password %></td>
            </tr>

        </table>


        <form action= "Next" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Return">
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the input `name` attribute. Try this,

```
<form action="form.jsp" method="get">
        <table cellspacing="5" border="0">
                <tr>
                     <td align="right">Email:</td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td align="right">Password:</td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td></td>
                     <td><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

For more info you can try this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `name` attribute in the form fields .

```
<input type="text" name="email"></td>
```

The value of "email" can be retrieved in JSP as :

```
String email = request.getParameter("email");
```

OR

```
${param.email}
```

OR

```
<c:out value="${param.email}"/> <%--(Using JSTL)--%>
```

Here are the [complete list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text) of attributes.

**name = string #**

*The name part of the name/value pair associated with this element for the purposes of form submission.*

Comment: +1. But as a side note: to avoid misunderstanding it would be better instead of `${param.value}` in your JSTL example use, for instance, `${param.paramName}` or something like that (IMHO). Just my first impression was what is this `${param.value}`? Because it is not the *value* of the parameter after the dot `.`, it is *parameter name* (i.e. the name of the real parameter).