# Changing variable value in jsp with button

Tags: java, html, jsp, button

I write dynamic web project in Java using JSP. I'm beginner.
I'm trying to write calendar on website.
In java code i use

```
<% 
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
Date date = new Date(); 
calendar.setTime(date);
...
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
...
numDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
weekStartDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
%>
```

I want to increase my value **month** by button in HTML to view next month but i don't know how connect JSP and HTML.
This is how i want to get the next month.

```
calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, numDays);
```

And after this submit page by JavaScript function

```
function goTo()
{
  document.form.submit()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking HTML to JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756528/linking-html-to-jsp-page)

Comment: where is your html ? post that as well .

Answer (score 0):

It is my code from JSP.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title</title>
    </head>

    <script>
        function goTo()
        {
          document.frm.submit()
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <div style="overflow-x:auto;">              
                <%
                    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String dateString = new String();
                    int day, month, year;
                    int numDays, weekStartDay, totalWeeks;

                    calendar.setTime(date);
                    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                    dateString += calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) +" "+ calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

                    numDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    weekStartDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                    calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, numDays);
                    totalWeeks = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
                %>          
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <%= iYear %> 
                        <%= iMonth %> 
                        <%= iMonth %> 
                        <\br>
                        <%= dateString %>

                        <button type="button" onclick="goTo()"> - <% iMonth--; %></button>
                        <button type="button" onclick="goTo()"> + <% iMonth++; %></button>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```